# Determinant of the square matrix $A$ where $a_{i,j}=|j-i|$

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, determinant, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $a_{i,j}=|j-i|$, show that the determinant is $D_n=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)2^{n-2}$

I have been struggling with this problem for a while now and I was hoping to get the slightest of nudges towards the solution. I would appreciate it if you phrase your hints in forms of questions so I can work through the idea. Please don't post a complete solution unless I asked, and thank you for your time. I wanted to obtain a recurrence relation between $D_n$ and $D_{n-1}$ but I failed. So far, I attempted to use Gaussian elimination on the first and last row and I obtained $(-1,1,\ldots,1)$ and $(1,1,\ldots,-1)$ for the first and last row respectively but I didn't know how to proceed from then on.

Comment: One solution is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2079959/81360)

Comment: [This is another](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2002620/81360) nice solution. By the way, I found the links that I am posting in the list of "Related" questions on the right.

Comment: I'm marking this post as a duplicate for now. However, I believe you should leave this post up since, as your question demonstrate, it's a bit difficult to find an answer online, which means that this question could be useful as a "signpost". If for some reason the linked post does not suit your purposes, let me know so that I can open the post to answers.

Comment: Notably (as a link in one of the linked posts mentions), this is a question from the 1969 Putnam exam.

Comment: I was hoping to get a hint not a complete solution. Is that not a good enough reason to open up this problem? My understanding is that the other post contains a complete solution which I am refraining from reading for now. I was hoping to work out the majority of the work myself but I was struggling and I just needed a nudge.

Comment: Hint: Let $U$ be the matrix with $1$ at the superdiagonals (i.e $j - i = 1$) and zero elsewhere. Let $L = U^T$ be its transpose. Since $U^n = L^n = 0$, the matrix at hand equals to
$$A = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kU^k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kL^k = (I-U)^{-2} U + L (I-L)^{-2}$$
This implies $$(I-U)^2A(I-L)^2 = U(I-L)^2 + (I-U)^2L$$
is a tridiagonal matrix and you can setup recurrence relations to compute the determinants.